# How to display a background control in transparent overlapping control?

Tags: winforms

I'm building a form with two layers of controls. The bottom layer is a set of Panels with defined properties, one of which is a color different from the form background. The top layer is a set of picture boxes I'm using to display a circle. I've set the PictureBox Background to Color.Transparent, and I've offset it from the underlying Panel by one pixel to get the form to draw the underlying Panel. However, the area around the circle in the PictureBox is displaying the Form Background color, not the panel color. I don't want to draw the circle in the Panel, because I want the circles to move between Panels, and actually look like just a circle that's floating across the form independent of the Panel board underneath. Think of the effect as moving a piece on a board game (you see the peg move across the board, possibly on a diagonal not following the normal game path, then stop in a place on the game).

How can I get the PictureBox to have the underlying Form and panels show through, not just the form background color? I'm using C# Visual Studio 2010, and I'm not a terribly experienced programmer, so a code example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way around the problem. I got rid of the Panels for the spaces in the game, and instead drew them as rectangles on the form's background image.